# SQL Bulk Insert from unknown file name

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I am needing to bulk insert the data from .csv files into my database.

These .csv files however arrive with unknown names, e.g.
"es[a_random_date_and_time_here]person.csv"

Atm I have...

```
BULK INSERT TestDB.dbo.tblPersonsImport

 FROM 'C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Test\es20150301195906person.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    )
```

Which works but, this would require manual editing of each stored procedure everytime.

Can I modify this to handle files that come with any name on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such situation you can use dynamic sql and call sp with specified file name. See code below:

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.LoadFile (@fileName varchar(250))
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @query varchar(4000) = 
    '
    BULK INSERT TestDB.dbo.tblPersonsImport

     FROM ''C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Test\'+@fileName+'''
        WITH
        (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
        )
    '

    exec (@query)
    return (0)
GO
```